# Create a nullable column using SQL Server SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I create a temp table using a `select into` in SQL Server, is there a way to specify that a column should be nullable?  I have a multi-step process where I'm making a temp table by selecting a lot of columns (which is why I'm not doing a `create table #tmp (...)`).  After I make that temp table, I'm updating some columns and some of those updates might null out a field.

I know I could do an `alter table alter column` statement to achieve what I want, but I'm curious about whether there's a way to specify this in the `select` itself.  I know you can inline `cast` your columns to get the desired datatype, but I can't see how you specify nullability.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Nullability is inherited from the source column.

You can lose or gain nullability with an expression:

Example (constant literals appear to be problematic - need a good NOOP function which can return NULL):

```
CREATE TABLE SO5465245_IN
    (
     a INT NOT NULL
    ,b INT NULL
    ) ;
GO

SELECT  COALESCE(a, NULL) AS a
       ,ISNULL(b, 0) AS b
       ,COALESCE(10, NULL) AS c1
       ,COALESCE(ABS(10), NULL) AS c2
       ,CASE WHEN COALESCE(10, NULL) IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(10, NULL) ELSE NULL END AS c3
INTO    SO5465245_OUT
FROM    SO5465245_IN ;
GO

SELECT  TABLE_NAME
       ,COLUMN_NAME
       ,IS_NULLABLE
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME LIKE 'SO5465245%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
       ,ORDINAL_POSITION ;
GO

DROP TABLE SO5465245_IN ;
GO

DROP TABLE SO5465245_OUT ;
GO
```

Comment: `NULLIF` seems to work great when using a column.  Your answer made me think to try `COALESCE(col_name, null)` which universally works without needing to invent an impossible value.  However, there is one situation when neither appears to work, and that is when you are selecting a literal like `select nullif('asdf', '~') as Value into _Test`.  NULLIF/COALESCE seems like it's good enough, but is there any other way that works in all situations?

Comment: @mattmc3 - some operators circumvent that (for instance, ABS works int eh example above), but NULLIF isn't enough.

Answer (score 20):

This soulution I've recently come up with and though I should share:

```
select top 0
  B.*
into
  TargetTable
from
  SourceTable as A
    left join SourceTable as B on 1 = 0
```

This effectively creates a duplicated structure of `SourceTable` in `TargetTable` with all columns nullable (at least in sql2008).

Comment: This is a really great solution! I was trying to emulate tSQLt's FakeTable on a synonym we have that points to a view on another server, and this is a perfect, clean way to handle it.

Comment: Great solution indeed.

Answer (score 6):

CONVERT will make your columns nullable, and works for literals/constants too. Tested in SQL Server 2005/2008.

```
SELECT 
    SomeText = CONVERT(varchar(10), 'literal'),
    SomeNumber = CONVERT(int, 0)
INTO SO5465245

INSERT SO5465245 VALUES (null, null)

SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SO5465245'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

DROP TABLE SO5465245
```

Comment: THIS... you can even declare your 'fake' fields when using the syntax `SELECT blah INTO #TempTable FROM (Derived Table)`.  I needed nullable Date columns to be created as placeholders for later temp table updates and so it looked like... `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, NULL) AS AssessmentDate FROM (Derived Table)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inherit nullablity for the destination column irrespective of the source table columns you can follow this query.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 INTO DestinationTable from SourceTable
```

if this was your query where COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 were not nullable in SourceTable then change the query as

```
SELECT NULL COLUMN1, NULL COLUMN2, NULL COLUMN3 INTO DestinationTable from SourceTable
```

so, this will allow you to insert null values in to the Destination table.

Comment: The down-side to this is you then have to drop the empty record

Comment: In SQL Server, this makes the column to become of type int - which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue - I wanted to use "select into", wanted all columns in the target table to be nullable & a repeatable approach where I didn't have to know the names of the fields in the source table.

```
select *
into dbo.I_Data
from
  (select 1[Z_1]) A
  full join (select null[Z_2], * from dbo.S_Data) B on A.Z_1 = B.Z_2
```

where 
  dbo.S_Data is the source data table and 
  [Z_*1] & [Z*_2] are two dummy columns used for the join

Then to clean up:

(a) Remove the row of nulls

```
delete dbo.I_Data where [Z_1] = 1
```

(b) Remove the dummy fields:

```
alter table dbo.I_Data 
  drop column [Z_1], [Z_2]
```

Regards.