# How to alter all columns without specifying column_name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to apply an alter statement to ALL the columns in a table without having to specify the column names? This would only be used in a temp table I need to clean up the duplicate data in a report.

Here's a sample of what I'm wondering if its possible:

```
select T1.Column1, T1.Column2, T1.Column3, T2.Column1, T2.Column2
into #templateTable
from Table1 T1
join Table2 T2 on T1.Column1 = T2.Column2

alter table #templateTable
alter column * null
```

All I really need is my #tempTable to allow null values in the columns that it originally gets data from which don't previously allow null values.

Lastly, there are 2 reasons I don't want to go through and edit each column:

1. There are many columns (~50) being pulled from at least 10 tables.
2. I don't know which ones allow null and researching which ones do would take me the next two days.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugly way, but it works in a SqlServer Management Studio, at least (can probably be used as "strings")

```
select 'alter table ' + table_name + ' alter column '+ column_name +' ' + data_type + 
(case 
  when character_maximum_length is not null and CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <> -1 then ' (' + CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as varchar) +')' 
  when CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 then '(MAX)'
  else '' end)  + ' null;'  from tempdb.information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = '<YOUR TABLE NAME>'
and IS_NULLABLE='NO';
```

copy result, paste and execute...

Comment: Added tempdb. before the information_schema and it worked exactly as I expected it! Awesome script!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely gathering what you are trying to accomplish with your temp tables, but as far as your first question you can query the sysobjects tables for your table's name and then alter each column in that table by looping through the syscolumns table

So lets say I want to loop through each column in the table master:

```
declare @i int
declare @colcount int
declare @column varchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @i = 1
set @colcount = (select MAX(colID) from syscolumns where ID = (select id from sysobjects        
where name = 'master'))

WHILE @i < @colcount
BEGIN

set @column = (select name from syscolumns where ID = (select id from sysobjects where name = 'master') and colid = @i)

set @sql = 'select top 1000 [' + @column + '] from master'

EXECUTE(@sql)

set @i = @i + 1

End
```

you can change @sql to whatever you need it to be and that should get it

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question [Create a nullable column using SQL Server SELECT INTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465245/create-a-nullable-column-using-sql-server-select-into)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a one time run...

```
select 'alter table xxx alter column ' + columnname + ...
from information_schema.columns
where ...
```

Copy and paste the result in a separate window and run.