# How to allow temporary tables to accept null values

Tags: sql, null, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

If you create temp tables using "insert into" in SQL Server it uses the first insert to determine whether a column accepts null value or not. if the first insert has null value the column become nullable otherwise it will be non-nullable.

Is there a way to create temp tables using "insert into" to accept null values?

Example

This works without any problem

```
Select 'one' as a , null as b
into #temp

insert into #temp
Select 'two' as a , 500 as b
```

However this throws "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'b'"

```
Select 'one' as a , 500 as b
into #temp

insert into #temp
Select 'two' as a , null as b
```

I know I could do `create Table` or `alter column` statement but I want to do it without rewriting hundreds of the existing queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465245/create-a-nullable-column-using-sql-server-select-into

Comment: Will it work if you insert fake record at the very beginning with `NULL` as value of both columns?

Comment: @Serg Yes, it will work but that's a wrong way to solve this

Comment: @Smith Do you know correct solution. If so, you can answer on your question thus everybody will know the solution. Or could you please clarify what is wrong in the way which works? Thank you.

Comment: Why the bump? This is already answered in the duplicate link above.

Comment: @Martin actually it's not, the duplicate link suggest rewriting but I'm looking a way to do it without rewriting

Comment: @Serg I don't know the correct solution but inserting a record is not the write way

Comment: It isn't possible without rewriting. If you don't create the table explicitly yourself then you just have to accept the way that SQL Server infers the column datatypes.

Comment: That's sad. I'm upgrading from SQLServer 2000 and I have more than 500  stored procedures with this issue.

Comment: I found the link to the duplicated question to have better information and it contained the answer to my issue.  This post however did not have the answers I was looking for. - Obi Wan.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465245/create-a-nullable-column-using-sql-server-select-into

Answer (score 9):

I would workaround this by explicitly creating temporary table before first insert.

```
create table #temp (a varchar(10) not null, b int null)
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(100), 'one') as a , CONVERT(int, 500) as b
into #temp

insert into #temp
Select 'two' as a , null as b

select * from #temp order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

(Un)fortunately, this question is too popular and appears at the top for Sybase ASE 15.7 as well, so just adding my answer for Sybase here.

For me neither of cast, convert or coalesce worked, but a case statement did (which is what coalesce is, but eh...)

```
select
    a = case when 1 = 0 then null else 'one' end, 
    b = case when 1 = 0 null else 500 end 
into #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I had a similar issue where I UNION NULLs to the initial query which *may* have helped the OP.

```
Select 'one' as a , 500 as b
into #temp
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL

insert into #temp
Select 'two' as a , NULL as b
```

Putting it here so the next time I need to do this and forget how...